# Can I rewrite this unionWith-like function with Applicative instead Monad?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, monads, applicative

I tried to write a function similar to [Data.Map.unionWith](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.15/containers-0.5.6.2/Data-Map-Lazy.html#g:9), but may fail. The original one uses Maybe, which indeed is a Monad, so the monadic one just works fine for me. but I wonder if it can be rewritten with Applicative, since I fmapped it with pure just to satisfy the type requirement of unionWith. Or with other function in Data.Map instead of unionWith?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Monad
import Data.Map
unionWithM :: (Monad m, Traversable t)
          => (forall a. (a -> a -> a)
              -> t a
              -> t a
              -> t a
             )
          -> (v -> v -> m v)
          -> t v
          -> t v
          -> m (t v)
unionWithM u f a b = sequenceA (u f' (pure <$> a) (pure <$> b))
  where f' x y = join $ f <$> x <*> y

unionWithOriginal :: Ord k => (a -> a -> Maybe a) -> Map k a -> Map k a -> Maybe (Map k a)
unionWithOriginal f a b = sequenceA (unionWith f' (Just <$> a) (Just <$> b))
  where f' x y = join $ f <$> x <*> y
```

Comment: AFAICS, `unionWithM` is impossible: `unionWith` can feed the `v` result of `v -> v -> m v` to another call of `v -> v -> m v`. This is close to Kelisli composition, which requires monads.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can but you need an intermediate data structure.
The problem is you wrap the value of your Map before applying the function, which is why your `f'` is of type `m a -> m a -> m a`. To transform `f` to `f'` you need `join`, i.e. a Monad. The trick is to apply the function after the union.
For that you could use `(Maybe a, Maybe a)` which is a bit messy, so instead you can use the [These](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-These.html) data type. If we roll it out manually you get

```
data These a b = That a | This b | These a b

unionWith' f a b = let theses = unionWith These (That <$> a) (This <$> b)
                   in sequenceA (f' <$> theses)
    where f' (That a) = pure a
          f' (This b) = pure b
          f' (These a b) = f a b
```

If you use the `these` package you can simplify it to

```
 unionWith'' f a b = sequenceA $ alignWith (these pure pure f)  a b
```

Comment: I see a `let` with no `in`.

Comment: I have to say that I don't really like this solution though I upvoted it, well, it works anyway, thanks.

Comment: @dfeur indeed. Fixed

Comment: @CosmiaLuna Jus curious. What don't you like about this solution ?

Comment: @mb14 I do not know, just somewhat..., maybe the intermediate data structure?